# Combining Multiple Select Statements

Tags: sql, select

I'm looking to select multiple rows of data from 2 tables, I also need to select case; for example:

```
select h.enquiry_id, h.hire_type, h.dry_drop, h.mobile_timestamp, s.signature_time, s.printed_name,
Convert (varchar,(s.signature_time-h.mobile_timestamp),108) as difference
from hire h
join signature s on s.hire_id = h.id
where s.typ = 0

select case
when dry_drop = 0 then 'no'
when dry_drop = 1 then 'yes'
end as dry_drop
from hire

select case
when collection = 0 then 'no'
when collection = 1 then 'yes'
end as collection
from hire
```

I need to know how to combine these three select statements into one, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Write those `case when ... end` in 1st query? is that you want?

Comment: So what is your problem? That you don't know how to get both hire records with and without a matching signature of type 0 in your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use like this :

```
SELECT h.enquiry_id
,h.hire_type
,h.dry_drop
,h.mobile_timestamp
,s.signature_time
,s.printed_name
,Convert(VARCHAR, (s.signature_time - h.mobile_timestamp), 108) AS difference
,CASE 
    WHEN dry_drop = 0
        THEN 'no'
    WHEN dry_drop = 1
        THEN 'yes'
    END AS dry_drop_Case
,CASE 
    WHEN COLLECTION = 0
        THEN 'no'
    WHEN COLLECTION = 1
        THEN 'yes'
    END AS collection_Case
FROM hire h
INNER JOIN signature s ON s.hire_id = h.id
WHERE s.typ = 0
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: Thank you!! This helped, so simple.. i'm hitting myself right now!

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Comment: Yes, You are right. If you see my answer you will find that i only posted his code. He did write the code but he don't know how to integrate the three pieces. All i did was integrate those three pieces.